# Determine the line connecting the two most extreme points

Tags: r, dataframe, geometry, rstudio, lapply

I have to determine the line connecting the two most extreme points in the x direction and the two most extreme points in the y direction from my set of points.

My points with coords:

```
x <- rpois(200,485000)
y <- rpois(200,625000)
dane <- data.frame(x,y)
dane$ID  <- seq(1,200)
df_punkty <- st_as_sf(dane,coords = c("x","y"))
st_crs(df_punkty) <- 2180
```

I tried to make the table with the most extreme points like this:

```
min_x  <- dane[which.min(dane$x),]
max_x  <- dane[which.max(dane$x),]
X  <- full_join(min_x, max_x, by = c("y", "x"))
dane[dane$x == min_x,]
X$ID =1
min_y  <- dane[which.min(dane$y),]
max_y  <- dane[which.max(dane$y),]
Y  <- full_join(min_y, max_y, by = c("y", "x"))
Y$ID = 1

tab <- data.frame(X,Y)
head(tab)
```

[image]

But in the next step an error appears (the line with geom_lines)- "Error: variable is.matrix(x) && is.numeric(x) has not TRUE"

```
list_lines <- split(tab,f=tab$ID) 
list_lines <- lapply(list_lines,as.matrix) 
list <-split(tab[,1:2],f=tab$ID) 
geom_lines <- lapply(list,st_linestring,dim="XY")
```

I suppose the table makes that error, but I have no idea how to do away with it... Any ideas?

Comment: What is your expected result? A plot?

Comment: Yes, i have to make a plot with that lines

Comment: Don't provide information as image which can be text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot going on in your code. Here is my best attempt at correcting the things I was seeing.

- It's generally good to include your dependencies (`sf` in this case)
- You can create a dataframe with the functions directly inside
- `st_set_crs` allows you to use it in a pipe (not sure if EPSG 2180 is significant)
- If you want the min or max of a column of a data frame, you can just use `min` and `max`, instead of using `which.min` and `which.max` and then indexing, which actually returns a 1x1 data frame rather than a "scalar" (R actually just has length 1 vectors)
- `st_linestring` takes a matrix as its argument for points, not a list. This is the source of the error (literally, `is.matrix(x) is not TRUE`)

After all that, you can get the line as your code seems to want. However, this is possibly not the "two most extreme points in the x direction and the two most extreme points in the y direction from my set of points", as you said. What this has actually done is take the most extreme `x` and `y` values in `dane`, created new points that correspond to them (which did not exist in the original `df_punkty`) and drawn the line between them. If you want to draw the longest line between `x-y` *pairs* on `df_punkty`, then I'll need to edit this answer...

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
dane <- tibble(
  x = rpois(200, 485000),
  y = rpois(200,625000),
  ID = 1:200
  )

df_punkty <- dane %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("x","y")) %>%
  st_set_crs(2180)

extremes <- matrix(, 2, 2)
extremes[1, 1] <- min(dane$x)
extremes[2, 1] <- max(dane$x)
extremes[1, 2] <- min(dane$y)
extremes[2, 2] <- max(dane$y)

extremes %>%
  st_linestring() %>%
  plot()
```

EDIT: Here are the lines that connect the points with the extremes of x and y values:

```
x_ex <- y_ex <- matrix(, 2, 2)
x_ex[1, 1:2] <- as.matrix(dane[which.min(dane$x), 1:2])
x_ex[2, 1:2] <- as.matrix(dane[which.max(dane$x), 1:2])
y_ex[1, 1:2] <- as.matrix(dane[which.min(dane$y), 1:2])
y_ex[2, 1:2] <- as.matrix(dane[which.max(dane$y), 1:2])

plot(df_punkty)
plot(x_ex %>% st_linestring(), add = TRUE)
plot(y_ex %>% st_linestring(), add = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: I see my mistakes now...I'll try to edit your code to make my two lines between x-y pairs. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Again you should be clear about what you are looking for. Is it line between points with greatest difference in x? greatest difference in y? or greatest distance between them?

Comment: What does that mean though? Each point has an x and a y value

Comment: I have to take one point most to the right and most to the left from `dane` . And then make a line connecting these two points. And do the same up and down...I don't know how to explain it better with my english... I can draw how the final result should look only... :)